# GCP, terraform is installed on GCP project-A 'test-instance' instance, using terraform code, how to deploy/create instance on project-B?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

GCP, terraform is installed on GCP project-A 'test-instance' instance, using terraform how to deploy instance on project-B ?

I was able to do it using gcloud command, does anyone knows how to do it ?

```
provider "google" {
  project = "project-b"
  region = "us-central1"
  zone = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
  name = "terraform-instance"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    # A default network is created for all GCP projects 
    network = "default"
    access_config {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I was getting bellow error message:-
google_compute_instance.vm_instance: Creating...
Error: Error loading zone 'us-central1-c': googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for 'projects/jana-project-b/zones/us-central1-c', forbiddenon main.tf line 7, in resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance":
7: resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {

Comment: please find terraform code:-
    provider "google" {
      project = "project-b"
      region  = "us-central1"
      zone    = "us-central1-c"
    }
    
    resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
      name         = "terraform-instance"
      machine_type = "f1-micro"
    
      boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
          image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        }
      }
    
      network_interface {
        # A default network is created for all GCP projects
        network       = "default"
        access_config {
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Please edit your code into your question and use proper formatting blocks for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is around access control.
You are trying to run terraform from a VM lives in `Project-A` and terraform code wants to create a new VM (or other resource) in `Project-B`.

By default, service account attached to `Project-A` VM does not have enough rights to create any resource in `Project-B`. To solve this, you can create a service account at Folder level (or Org level) which has permissions to create VM in required projects and then you can attach that service account to the VM which runs terraform.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, thanks Pradeep, but Project-A and Project-B are in different Organizations, is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: @Janardhan - What's the usecase you are trying to solve? Why would you want some other organization to create/manage resources in your organization?

Comment: I am working on Multi-account(project) deployment on GCP, hence I need access to other organization project resources, we use terraform tool to deploy instances on another project.

Comment: You can have mutiple project or folder within one organization so why do you want to create multiple org?

Comment: Generally you have one organization for one company and then you can have multiple folder for different department and under that you can have multiple projects for different teams

Comment: thanks Pradeep, but my usecase is to deploy instances on other organization projects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Terraform Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) using `.tfvars` files and multiple [Terraform Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html). You can then switch between workspaces and apply the tfvars for each particular project separately.

e.g.

```
# variables.tf

variable "project_id" {
  type        = string
}
```

And then use the variable in your terraform config:

```
# main.tf

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region = "us-central1"
  zone = "us-central1-c"
}
```

The tfvars will then look like this:

```
# vars/dev.tfvars

project_id = "my-dev-project"
```

Full invocation within your workspace (see the docs) can then be done using plan/apply as you would normally do:

```
terraform workspace select dev

terraform plan -var-file vars/dev.tfvars
```

Comment: Thanks petomalina, will try this approach.